# Firefox is not loading my7 angularjs bower_components

Tags: angularjs, firefox, bower

people!

I'm creating a site with AngularJS that is working fine on every single browser, except for Firefox. 
When I use firebug, the console shows "400 Bad Request" errors while trying to get the bower_components for the modal and ui-router services.

Could you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Please, provide the code you are trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already solved it, it was a problem of Firefox not reconizing / instead of .